# using return from inner class to exit the outer method

Tags: android, firebase, inner-classes

In my signup activity, I need to check if the user entered an email address that exists in my database( the application is restricted to the users whose email addresses are added to the database), when I use the following code, the problem is that the "return;" is in the inner class and so the app shows an error message for few seconds and then proceeds to the signup, and I can't use an intermediate variable because the changes in the inner class won't be passed to the outer class.

```
       myRef.child("administration").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {


                         UserInformation user = new UserInformation();
                         user = snapshot.child(function).getValue(UserInformation.class);


                         if(!(email.equals(user.getEmail())))
                    {   editTextEmail.setError("you are not authorized yet");
                        editTextEmail.requestFocus(); 
                        return;                            
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });




    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener( .........
```

what solution do you suggest ?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: You can't return a containing method from an inner class, because, one, it's a completely separate class, and, two, there's no guarantee that the method hasn't already returned.

Comment: In case the condition is true, it should show the error message and stays in the same activity and not proceed to createUserWithEmailAndPassword, for Alex Mamo : the conditions that are not inside an inner class, it works fine but the problem is when the return in this case is that the return doesn't affect directly the outer method. So how can I make it not proceed to createUserWithEmailAndPassword ( the rest of the code).

Comment: TheWanderer : so what is the alternative to implement what I need  ?